# Where is my "unpermitted parameter: :passenger" Rails error coming from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I am building a flight booking app with Rails that lets you select airports, date and number of passengers. Once you select the airports and dates, it gives you radio buttons to select which flight you want and, once you click submit, you are taken to a booking confirmation page where you are asked to provide passenger info.

The confirmation page(bookings#new) has a nested form to include passengers in the booking object. To do this, I have first set the following models and associations:

```
class Passenger < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :booking

end
```

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :flight
    has_many :passengers 

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :passengers 

    
end
```

And the relevant migrations that result in the following schema tables:

```
  create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "flight_id"
    t.integer "passenger_id"
  end
```

```
  create_table "passengers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "booking_id"
    t.index ["booking_id"], name: "index_passengers_on_booking_id"
  end
```

From what I understand, the flow goes like this:
User selects flight -> User submits flight, goes to Booking#new through the #new method on my controller:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @booking = Booking.new
        @flight = Flight.find(params[:flight_id]) 
        params[:passengers_number].to_i.times do #params passed from select flight page
            @booking.passengers.build
            end
    end
```

Then, the form I built takes over on new.html.erb:

```
 <%= form_with model: @booking, url: bookings_path do |f| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :flight_id, value: @flight.id %>

            <% @booking.passengers.each_with_index do |passenger, index| %>
                <%= f.fields_for passenger, index: index do |form| %>

                <h4><%= "Passenger #{index+1}"%> <br> </h4>

                    <%= form.label :name, "Full name:" %>
                    <%= form.text_field :name %>

                    <%= form.label :email, "Email:" %>
                    <%= form.email_field :email %>

             <% end %>
        <% end %>

            <%= f.submit "Confirm details"%>
        <% end %>
```

I fill it in with names and emails, click 'Confirm details' and I get this error on my terminal:

```
Unpermitted parameter: :passenger
```

Why? I have set `accepts_nested_attributes_for :passengers` on my Booking model, my booking_params method is:

```
 def booking_params
        params.require(:booking).permit(:flight_id,
            :passengers_attributes => [:name, :email, :passenger_id, :created_at, :updated_at])
      end
```

and my #create method is:

```
 def create
        @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)

        respond_to do |format|
            if @booking.save
              format.html { redirect_to @booking, notice: "booking was successfully created." }
              format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @booking }
            else
                format.html { redirect_to root_path,  alert: "booking failed, #{@booking.errors.full_messages.first}" , status: :unprocessable_entity }
                format.json { render json: @booking.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
          end
    end
```

Is there something I am not permitting properly? Note that if I set `booking_params` as `params.require(:booking).permit!` it gives me an `unknown attribute 'passenger' for Booking` error. But I have defined associations and database on passenger and booking, at least to my knowledge.

Thanks in advance

Edit: The server log that generates the error is:

```
Started POST "/bookings" for ::1 at 2021-08-27 17:52:17 +0300
Processing by BookingsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "booking"=>{"flight_id"=>"5", "passenger"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"Jason Smason", "email"=>"jason@ymail.com"}, "1"=>{"name"=>"Joe Smith", "email"=>"Joe@smith.com"}}}, "commit"=>"Confirm details"}
Unpermitted parameter: :passenger
```

Edit2: I followed PCurell's advice and changed my `fields_for` to                 `<%= f.fields_for :passengers, passenger, index: index do |form| %>` and my booking params to `:passenger => [:name, :email, :passenger_id, :created_at, :updated_at])`

That generated a different error: `Unpermitted parameter: passengers_attributes'. So I changed my controller's` booking_params` to:

```
def booking_params 
        params.require(:booking).permit(:flight_id, 
            :passengers_attributes => [:name, :email, :passenger_id, :created_at, :updated_at],
            :passenger => [:name, :email, :passenger_id, :created_at, :updated_at])
end
```

With that, I successfully managed to create a booking with 2 passengers. However, the passengers are blank; their `name` and `email` are nil. The log says:

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "booking"=>{"flight_id"=>"1", "passengers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"John Smith", "email"=>"John@smith.com"}}, "1"=>{"1"=>{"name"=>"Burger King", "email"=>"bk@bk.com"}}}}, "commit"=>"Confirm details"}
Unpermitted parameter: :0
Unpermitted parameter: :1
```

I might be able to hardcode :0 and :1 to pass, but surely that's not the Rails way. Is there a way to dynamically let them in? Or am I doing the whole thing wrong?

Comment: Hello, would you mind sharing the logs that you have on the request? It will allow me to see how your params are structured and we might solve it that way

It should be right above : `Unpermitted parameter: :passenger`

Comment: Your params, somewhere in them, have a `:passenger` object likely wrapping something else.  It could look something like this `:booking => {flight_id: 1, :passenger => {name: 'Todd',email:'todd@google.com', etc.}}`

Comment: @PCurell Sure, I added the log
@RockwellRice You're right, the only difference is it's `passenger => { "0" => {passenger params}, "1" => {passenger params}`. It's building them according to the `each_with_index` I added on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of `fields_for` is incorrect. When you look at [the example](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms) in the guide you will notice that there is no need to wrap it with an `.each` if used for a collection.

> ##### [10.2 Nested Forms](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms)
>
> The following form allows a user to create a `Person` and its
> associated addresses.
>
> ```html
> <%= form_with model: @person do |form| %>
>   Addresses:
>   <ul>
>     <%= form.fields_for :addresses do |addresses_form| %>
>       <li>
>         <%= addresses_form.label :kind %>
>         <%= addresses_form.text_field :kind %>
>
>         <%= addresses_form.label :street %>
>         <%= addresses_form.text_field :street %>
>         ...
>       </li>
>     <% end %>
>   </ul>
> <% end %>
> ```
>
> **When an association accepts nested attributes `fields_for` renders its block once for every element of the association.** In particular,
> if a person has no addresses it renders nothing. A common pattern is
> for the controller to build one or more empty children so that at
> least one set of fields is shown to the user. The example below would
> result in 2 sets of address fields being rendered on the new person
> form.
>
> ```rb
> def new
>   @person = Person.new
>   2.times { @person.addresses.build }
> end
> ```

When applying this to your code, removing the `.each` wrapper and changing `passenger` into `:passengers` should do the trick. You can access the `index` through the `FormBuilder` instance (`form`) passed to the `fields_for` block.

```html
<%= form_with model: @booking, url: bookings_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :flight_id, value: @flight.id %>

  <%= f.fields_for :passengers do |form| %>
    <h4>Passenger <%= form.index + 1 %></h4>

    <%= form.label :name, "Full name:" %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>

    <%= form.label :email, "Email:" %>
    <%= form.email_field :email %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Confirm details"%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Your form worked, when I changed my booking_params to             `:passengers_attributes => [:name, :email, :passenger_id, :created_at, :updated_at])`. Thanks!

Comment: @Grimhamr I was of the assumtion that you already had that, since you show that you have `:passengers_attributes` in the question. Note that you might want to add `:id` to the `:passengers_attributes` list and as hidden input in the form. For creation this is not needed, but if you ever plan on updating a booking all the existing passengers will be added as new passengers. Update uses `:id` to find the existing record and update it. There is also the `:_destroy` parameter, that allows object destruction. (Only if `allow_destroy: true` is set on `accepts_nested_attributes_for`)

Comment: If I may ask, why was my form not working? You said that `each` is unnecessary, but would it mess up the code? Also, what is the difference between `@booking.passengers` and `:passengers` in this case? How does the Rails engine interpret them differently?

Thanks again

Comment: @Grimhamr Let me start of by stating the difference between `@booking.passengers` and `:passengers`. `@booking.passengers` is a collection of `Passenger` instances. `:passengers` is not a variable but a [symbol](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Symbol.html), it is a literals (similar to a string `"passengers"`). When you pass a symbol to `fields_for` Rails will assume that this is the name of the association and internally builds the parameters to reflect this. I'm not quite sure what the parameters become when you pass an `Passenger` instance, since I've never done this myself.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rockwell Rice mentioned in his comment:

The problem here is that you are permitting the wrong param.

```
      def booking_params
        params.require(:booking).permit(:flight_id,
            :passenger => [:name, :email, :passenger_id, :created_at, :updated_at])
      end
```

Should work.

Although you might encounter another error.

I think that you are constructing your fields_for wrong.

This should be what you are looking for (and you will not have to change the booking_params)

```
<%= form_with model: @booking, url: bookings_path do |f| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :flight_id, value: @flight.id %>

            <% @booking.passengers.each_with_index do |passenger, index| %>
                <%= f.fields_for :passengers, passenger, index: index do |form| %>

                <h4><%= "Passenger #{index+1}"%> <br> </h4>

                    <%= form.label :name, "Full name:" %>
                    <%= form.text_field :name %>

                    <%= form.label :email, "Email:" %>
                    <%= form.email_field :email %>

             <% end %>
        <% end %>

            <%= f.submit "Confirm details"%>
        <% end %>
```

The above should work.

If you don't care too much about the index this would work as well:

```
         <%= form_with model: @booking, url: bookings_path do |f| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :flight_id, value: @flight.id %>
            <%= f.fields_for @booking.passengers do |form| %>

                <%= form.label :name, "Full name:" %>
                <%= form.text_field :name %>

                <%= form.label :email, "Email:" %>
                <%= form.email_field :email %>

            <% end %>

            <%= f.submit "Confirm details"%>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: I followed your advice, but now the passengers pass as empty; all their attributes are nil. The unpermitted parameters are now '0' and '1'

Comment: Never mind, got it to work by changing the form as Eliminator said, but your response was also helpful. Wish I could mark them both as correct!